# Command Prompt - Remove Directories With Specific Name Patern

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need us a bat file that will delete specific directories as long as they meat two specific critrera. 1) If the directory is older than 14 days 2) if the directory name consists of all numbers.

I have the following code that addresses only criteria 1, that is, the directory is older than 14 days. How would I extend this to then only delete those with numeric based names. `FORFILES /D -14 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rmdir @path /s /q"`

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I'm testing on a windows 7 but it will ultimately be run as a scheduled task on a server. I am not sure what version of windows server, I will investigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this will be run as a scheduled job, you should probably specify the root folder.

You can use FINDSTR to verify the name consists solely of digits. The leading and trailing dots are needed to match the quotes that are included in @file.

```
pushd "yourRootPath"
FORFILES /D -14 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE echo @file|>nul findstr /x .[0-9]*.&&rd /s /q @path"
```

However, the above may be quite slow. It would probably be faster to iterate the numeric folder names and then call FORFILES for each candidate folder to test the date:

```
pushd "yourRootPath"
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('"dir /b /ad|findstr /x [0-9]*"') do 2>nul forfiles /d -14 /m %%F /c "cmd /c rd /s /q @path"
```

Comment: @Squashman - Yes, read the preceding sentence concerning quotes.

Comment: I'm attempting the second solution because well who doesn't love efficiency. It is giving me `%%F was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: @LCaraway - I wrote the code assuming it would be used in a batch script, which requires doubled percents. Change all `%%F` to `%F` if used directly on the command line.

Comment: Yes. Forfiles puts quotes around.  But I suppose you could explicitly match quotes as well. `findstr /x \0x22[0-9]*\0x22`

Comment: @Squashman - Yes, but unnecessary to be that specific because the characters are guaranteed to be quotes - we just need to account for them so the exact match works.

Comment: @dbenham Thank you I got this to work though I had to make one change. I believe the `/f` after `forfiles` should be `/d`.. Can you confirm?

Comment: @dbenham changing the /f to /d deleted everything which looking back makes sense.. when run as you originally suggested it appears to curse through correctly but does not actually delete anything.. It prints the directory name though..

Comment: @LCaraway, `FORFILES` does not have an /F option so yes it was a TYPO.  You already know that the /D option is what is supposed to be used for your 14 days.

Comment: @LCaraway - Oops, sorry for the silly error. I edited the answer and corrected the typo.

Comment: Thanks! Works as expected!